# Is it possible to create a single framework by adding multiple framework in it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sdk, frameworks

I am creating a framework SDK for iOS, I want to include other Framework SDK in it. But other SDK should not be visible in newely created framework. Is it possible? I am not able to find any solution.

Comment: You can I think, just don't expose the header of the other SDK in your SDK, it wont be visible, but then it probably will still yell error if the user of the SDK implement the same other framework in their app, this just doesnt apply to system framework

Comment: I did, but after adding that framework to other project, it throws error of file missing.